# Returning views on route instead of controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a laravel site and being told that I should alway use a controller and never return a view directly on the route file. Now I can understand to use a controller if the page needs to do something, but is it also mandatory even if the page is just there to greet after you register?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/welcome', function () {
        return view('auth.pages.welcome');
    });
}
```

Is this about good practices or is there something I should know/do about it because it could have consequences??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's a bad practice. The good practice is keeping only routes in routes file, only data related logic in model classes, validation in request files, template in views etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing mandatory since it works, but as you said, using controller is a good practice it help you to keep your application tidy.

But if it sounds better for you do to it inline, just go for it. This will work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It is about best practice to just move the return statement to a controller, that is the main aim of using an MVC framework. There is no big consequence expected of this your code except it reduces readability of your code especially if your project has a lot of routes and many of such routes has pages returned from them or small logic embeded in them.